# Rails generate controller (under a namespace)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add a controller and its routes entry under a namespace (api) for which I am proceeding with `rails generate api/Users my_method`, which creates the files and entries as follows:

```
  create  app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb
  route   get "users/my_method"
  invoke  erb
  create  app/views/api/users
  create  app/views/api/users/my_method.html.erb
```

Everything worked fine apart from the routes entry. What I am assuming is it should create the routes entry as well under the correct namespace or it shouldn't create it at all, or I am doing something wrong.On the other hand when going with scaffold way it does correctly.

Is it something which we need to do it manually?

Using ruby 2.0 and rails 4 for the application.

Answer (score 4):

Type in terminal

```
rails generate scaffold Api::User username email

rake db:migrate
```

this is part of result

```
class Admin::ServicesController < ApplicationController
# GET /api/users
# GET /api/users.json
def index
 @api_users = Api::User.all
end
```

To do generate and I think you will understand everything, don't forget see new app structure :-), Good luck, and solve your problem quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can namespace your routes in your config/routes.rb like this

```
namespace :api do
  resources :user
end
```

Comment: I know by adding this manually I can solve this issue, but my question is why the rails generator is adding the wrong/invalid entry in the routes file. Rails generator should not create at all any entry on routes so that we can add it manually or it should add a valid entry like it does in scaffold case.